# How to insert line breaks in R Telegram bot$sendMessage

Tags: r, telegram, r-telegram-bot

I understand that it is possible to do line breaks in my telegram message just by entering to the next line (Example 1). However, I am dealing with variables and need to use the paste function to create my sentences (Example 2). Due to the paste function, I am not able to enter a line break in my telegram message. Please help!

Example 1:

```
library(telegram)

msg <- "This is your message
and this is the 2nd line"

bot$sendMessage(msg)
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
library(telegram)

x <- "123"

msg <- paste("This is your", x, 
"and this is the 2nd line")

bot$sendMessage(msg)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `paste("This is your", x, "\nand this is the 2nd line")` ?